# How to test method calls after async call in React/Redux/Jest tests

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

My component has a button which call method 'handleSave'. I simplified the code to make it more relevant.

That component method looks like:

```
handleSave = async () => {
  const response = await this.props.dispatchSave();
  this.props.dispatchNotification();
}
```

My test:

```
let dispatchSave = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({});
let dispatchNotification = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('Saved!');

it('should dispatch actions', () => {  
  const component = mount(<Comp dispatchSave={dispatchSave} dispatchNotification={dispatchNotification}>);
  const instance = component.find(Comp).instance() as Comp;
  instance.handleSave();

  expect(dispatchSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(dispatchNotification).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Saved!');
});
```

The first assertion works, but the second dispatch never gets asserted because it appears after an async call (if I move it above, it works).

How can I assert method calls after an async call?

Answer (score 0):

If `this.props.dispatchNotification` returns a promise (or you could make it return a promise), then you could return this result in a `handleSave` call.

```java
handleSave = async () => {
  const response = await this.props.dispatchSave();
  return this.props.dispatchNotification();
}
```

In test you need to prefix `it` with `async` keyword and `await` for your function call.

```java
it('should dispatch actions', async () => {  
  const component = mount(<Comp dispatchSave={dispatchSave} dispatchNotification={dispatchNotification}>);
  const instance = component.find(Comp).instance() as Comp;
  await instance.handleSave();

  expect(dispatchSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(dispatchNotification).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Saved!');
});
```